# nested views in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-router

I'm using angularjs 1.5.3 with ui-router.
my website works as the navbar(the index html page) is permanent and all the other page is ui-view.
I'm building now new page that will have inside a box with another navbar. the navbar buttons will change only the page in the box, as a different ui-view.

I read a lot of examples in the internet but sill didn't find some thing similar to this, is that possible ?

Comment: so literally speaking you want certain view to share navbar and remaining view to have another nav-bar??

Comment: Look for named views and abstract views in ui-router documentation

Comment: can i do <nav><div ui-view><nav><div ui-view='child'></div><nav><div><nav>?